# Unix cat command problems

Tags: linux, unix

I started a command line online course last night. I was playing around with some basic commands and for some reason, every time I use cat mydoc.txt or mydoc.docx, it only outputs question marks and other random symbols to the terminal. I searched this site and google and can't find an exact solution to this specific problem. I came across a couple of sites that said maybe try changing the file permission but that didn't seem to affect the output.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Permissions only control if you can read a file or not, not what you read. Using `cat` on some binary file like a `docx` file (whatever that _really_ is) does not make any sense. Binary data is nothing you can read as a human. In the end it simply depends on what the content of that file is. Note: this means the content in a basic, literal way, not as it appears by some application interpreting the content and showing you the interpretation, that is a _huge_ difference.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that! Then how can I display the contents of a file to the terminal? Docx is my Microsoft word document extension.. in the course we learned cat filename will display the text of the document

Comment: @user3344239, `cat` will display the text, of a text document.  It does nothing smart to extract text from a `docx` file, though.  To get a lightly better look inside any file, try the `hd` or `hexdump` command.  That can show hex values for anything, and alongside that output, it can display printable characters found, and dots for unprintables.

Comment: In other words, the "text" in a file designed for some special program like Word or Excel is not "raw text" but is all encoded up with font and spacing and formatting and god-knows-what (compression too?), so that it is only "sensible" for that particular program to interpret. You should be pretty OK with any *.txt file though; Windows .txt extension usually means "raw text". Oh, and running the Unix `file` command on a file will tell you the file type first.

Comment: i tried typing xdg-open and it says that the command is not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.doc` file contains binary [8 bit bytes in the range 0x00-0xFF] bytes that MS word knows how to handle.  It has many internal subsections, tables, etc.

When you `cat` it to a terminal, it's just a stream of binary bytes.  The terminal program tries to interpret this as text.  It will try to use UTF8 encoding of unicode, which has special variable length [1-4 bytes] UTF "characters" that are called "codepoints".

Not all 1-4 byte sequences produce valid UTF8 codepoints.  When the terminal program finds a non-codepoint sequence, it outputs a `?`.

Otherwise, the terminal program will try to output what it thinks is the correct character.  This might be a german vowel with an *umlaut* over it.  Or, a character in the Chinese character set.

That's what you get if the terminal program has the particular character set/font set loaded.  If the given set is not available, the terminal program will [again] output a `?`

Note that all of this is just "best effort" by the terminal program to "interpret" as text, what is, in reality, just a random binary sequence.  It's similar to trying to interpret `cat /usr/bin/cat`, which is a binary file that really has no text to speak of.

If the file you `cat` *is* just a simple text file [or utf8 encoded], what you did *will* work.  To see, use a simple text file and do (e.g.) `cat /etc/passwd`.  Or, do `echo abc > /tmp/foo` and then `cat /tmp/foo`

Of course, if your goal was just to open the `.doc` under linux/*BSD, etc., there *are* programs that understand these files.  Of note: `libreoffice` is a full open source suite of programs similar to MS office and what you would want is `LibreOffice Writer`.  If you've got a standard distro installed (e.g. ubuntu or fedora), it will probably already be installed.

Comment: is there a command to open a word document then? I tried doing cp myFile.docx test.txt to copy its contents to a plain text document but that still didnt work